# React.FC<SpecificProps> is not assignable to React.FC<GenericProps>, but props are assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-functional-component

I have props for component:

```
interface SpecyficProps {
  data: {
    body: string
  }
}
```

which are assignable to abstract props

```
interface ComponentProps {
  data: {
    [propName: string]:
      | string
      | number
      | ComponentProps
      | ComponentProps[]
      | undefined
  }
}

const specyficProps: SpecyficProps = {
  data: {
    body: 'xxxx',
  },
}

// ok
const universalProps: ComponentProps = specyficProps
```

but `FunctionalComponents` using this props are not:

```
const specyficComponent: React.FC<SpecyficProps> = ({ data }) => null

// error
const universalComponent: React.FC<ComponentProps> = specyficComponent
```

```
Type 'FC<SpecyficProps>' is not assignable to type 'FC<ComponentProps>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps>' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<SpecyficProps>'.
      Type 'PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps>' is not assignable to type 'SpecyficProps'.
        Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
          Property 'body' is missing in type '{ [propName: string]: string | number | ComponentProps | ComponentProps[] | undefined; }' but required in type '{ body: string; }'.(2322)
input.tsx(16, 5): 'body' is declared here.
```

**How can I define this component types to be assignable?**

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOYAOxiSk3STgGFdJ6lGAFHGADOcAN6k4cACYoYKAFzjJUuAG0wQgHIoQSJcJhQGAcwC6ClargAfOIeP0TV1XfoBXEACNmLqXa5wCF4BIWE-W05uYL4YQQgRNTMIu3d6aSRMBiRpFQBfUgLSBiYWNjgAZTAkNABPLLR4kWUpWXklCWsvCGlagyNTfMLyNGDDe2q6hqbhJSqa+uBGsLgAXhaZOUUNqW7epXxKI8p8ABp886KAeiu4CABrUlH6cbTgADdmYRQAGxmlQI8WIzNYTBbTMJPMbwYSTRZoQExRhKZDoGAAOgAYhwADzzKZLGYAPlBAAoxJt5HA8gBKNYkjw-H7kG5wZg4KBQl7wN6fKDfH6IkIwFHEDHYnFC4FhEnrWHgpZSxhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error derives from `strictFunctionTypes`, [introduced in 2.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html). As this will compile, one ["solution"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictFunctionTypes=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOYAOxiSk3STgGFdJ6lGAFHGADOcAN6k4cACYoYKAFzjJUuAG0wQgHIoQSJcJhQGAcwC6ClargAfOIeP0TV1XfoBXEACNmLqXa5wCF4BIWE-W05uYL4YQQgRNTMIu3d6aSRMBiRpFQBfUgLSBiYWNjgAZTAkNABPLLR4kWUpWXklCWsvCGlagyNTfMLyNGDDe2q6hqbhJSqa%20uBGsLgAXhaZOUUNqW7epXxKI8p8ABp886KAeiu4CABrUlH6cbTgADdmYRQAGxmlQI8WIzNYTBbTMJPMbwYSTRZoQExRhKZDoGAAOgAYhwADzzKZLGYAPlBAAoxJt5HA8gBKNYkjw-H7kG5wZg4KBQl7wN6fKDfH6IkIwFHEDHYnFC4FhEnrWHgpZSxhAA) is to turn this off. One alternative approach is to introduce hierarchies in your interfaces. Let the lowermost interface be a subtype of the highermost one, and it will compile. Essentially these changes

```js
type HigherMost = SpecyficProps | ComponentProps 

const specyficComponent: React.FC<HigherMost> = ({ data }) => null

// ok
const universalComponent: React.FC<ComponentProps> = specyficComponent
```